# Multicolumn error when used within a newcommand with \@ifstar

Tags: tables, macros, errors, multicolumn

I am new to writing packages and am coming across an error that I can't unravel, I would appreciate any help that you can provide. I am writing a few macros which are meant to be used within a tabular environment:

```
\newcommand{\topics}{\@ifstar{\topicsStar}{\topicsNoStar}}
\newcommand{\topicsNoStar}[1]{\multicolumn{2}{|p{2in}|}{test}}
\newcommand{\topicsStar}{&&}
```

When I call

```
\topicsNoStar{stuff}
```

the output is correct.

When I call

```
\topics{stuff}
```

I get the error message: `!Misplaced \omit. \multispan ->\omit \@multispan`

What is confusing me is the difference between the two calls - in my mind, they should be doing the same thing, but the output is not the same.

Now, I do plan to include `@`'s in the commands above in the final version, but, to debug, I wanted to be able to call them outside the style file. Also, the argument to NoStar is not used, it will be placed into the multicolumn once this is working correctly.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: Some newer solutions using xparse expandable command definition → [longtable - Using \multicolumn to remove vertical lines in row works, but not when used in a command called by in an \@ifstar conditional - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/662900/using-multicolumn-to-remove-vertical-lines-in-row-works-but-not-when-used-in-a)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution is built on the requirement suggested by Heiko in [! Misplaced `\omit` error](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.text.tex/_3QLLTBgrKo/discussion).

[`etextools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etextools) provides fully-expandable conditioning commands to allow `\multicolumn` to be considered as "the first element in the cell". This is not currently the case in your example, since `\@ifstar` is not fully expandable, while `\FE@ifstar` is a `F`ully `E`xpandable version:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etextools}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etextools
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\topics}[1]{%
  \FE@ifstar{#1}
    {test & test}% starred
    {\multicolumn{2}{|p{2in}|}{#1}\@gobble}}% non-starred
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{1in}p{1in}|}
  \topics{stuff} \\
  \topics* \\
  \topics{some more stuff} \\
  \topics* \\
  \topics*
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

`\multicolumn` must be the first thing in a table cell and a command with a star variant defined in the usual way hides `\multicolumn` after some unexpandable token. Without packages you can do in the following way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\topics}[1]{%
  \if*\detokenize{#1}%
    &%
  \else
    \multicolumn{2}{|p{2in}|}{#1}%
  \fi
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{1in}p{1in}|}
  \topics{stuff} \\
  \topics* \\
  \topics{some more stuff} \\
  \topics* \\
  \topics*
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative, using my `\NewDocumentCommandOptionalInTabular` macro in [another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/681044/250119).

```
\documentclass{article}

% ======== copy paste this part ========
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \NewDocumentCommandOptionalInTabular #1 #2 #3 {
  \NewDocumentCommandOptionalInTabular_aux:xnnn {\exp_not:c{\cs_to_str:N #1-aux}} #1 {#2} {#3}
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \NewDocumentCommandOptionalInTabular_aux:nnnn #1 #2 #3 #4 {
  \cs_new:Npn #2 { \noalign \bgroup #1 }
  \NewDocumentCommand #1 {#3} { \egroup #4 }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \NewDocumentCommandOptionalInTabular_aux:nnnn {x}
\ExplSyntaxOff
% ======== end ========


\NewDocumentCommandOptionalInTabular \topics {s} {\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\topicsStar}{\topicsNoStar}}
\newcommand{\topicsNoStar}[1]{\multicolumn{2}{|p{2in}|}{#1}}
\newcommand{\topicsStar}{test & test}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{1in}p{1in}|}
  \topics{stuff} \\
  \topics* \\
  \topics{some more stuff} \\
  \topics* \\
  \topics*
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Output is as you expect.

[image: output]

---

An example where the expandable star test breaks the kerning in the following character:

```
%! TEX program = pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etextools}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etextools
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\test}[1]{%
  \FE@ifstar{#1}
    {123}
    {456}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\test VA  % ← see the space between V and A here is much larger than that of...

VA  % the space between V and A in this line.

\end{document}
```

Comment: * note. there's a way to automatically determine the current template but LuaLaTeX only / or requires patching the kernel code [tables - Determine current tabular column number with LuaLaTeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/592627/determine-current-tabular-column-number-with-lualatex)