# Misplaced \omit. \multispan with \newcommand defined with optional argument

Tags: tables, macros, errors, multicolumn, columns

I'm trying to build my own cookbook-style, which has an ingredient makro. Sometimes the ingredients should be separated and have a headline, so I tried with an optional argument. A minimum example looks like this:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\newcommand{\ingredient}[3][]{
    #1 #2 & #3 \\
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{r|l}        
        \ingredient[\multicolumn{2}{l}{Head} \\]{test1}{test2}
        \ingredient[test3]{test4}{test5}
        \ingredient{test6}{test7}
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

What's wrong with this code? I get the following error message:

```
! Misplaced \omit.
\multispan -&gt;\omit 
                   \@multispan 
l.7 ...[\multicolumn{2}{l}{Head} \\]{test1}{test2}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Tabular material is *really* picky about what is allowed to go "before" a line. In particular, it has to be fully expandable.

Hence, even the *assignment* which `\ingredient` needs to do to check for its optional argument is enough to start the line, and then `\multicolumn` is no longer allowed to appear.

The easiest way to remedy this is to make the first argument of `\ingredient` mandatory:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\newcommand{\ingredient}[3]{
    #1 #2 & #3 \\
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{r|l}        
        \ingredient{\multicolumn{2}{l}{Head} \\}{test1}{test2}
        \ingredient{test3}{test4}{test5}
        \ingredient{}{test6}{test7}
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for a working example, but as this "headline" is really seldomly used it would be much more convenient to have it as an optional parameter. Is there no way to make it work as an optional parameter? Ideally I could also get rid of the "\multicolum{2}{1}{VARIABLE} \\"-stuff.

Comment: Nope. You could make two commands, one with two and one with three arguments.

Comment: Thank you. I found a solution by adding a new command just like you proposed.

Answer (score 10):

You *can* retain your original syntax and have a single macro with an optional parameter if you use `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand` from the [`xparse` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xparse}

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\ingredient}{O{} m m}{%
    #1 #2 & #3 \\%
}%

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{r|l}        
        \ingredient[\multicolumn{2}{l}{Head} \\]{test1}{test2}
        \ingredient[test3]{test4}{test5}
        \ingredient{test6}{test7}
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can "creatively" use `noalign` to implement the functionality. In the following code, I define a function `\NewDocumentCommandOptionalInTabular` that works similar to that of `\NewDocumentCommand` except that you *can* use optional argument (or star) as you want.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

% ======== copy paste this part ========
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \NewDocumentCommandOptionalInTabular #1 #2 #3 {
  \NewDocumentCommandOptionalInTabular_aux:xnnn {\exp_not:c{\cs_to_str:N #1-aux}} #1 {#2} {#3}
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \NewDocumentCommandOptionalInTabular_aux:nnnn #1 #2 #3 #4 {
  \cs_new:Npn #2 { \noalign \bgroup #1 }
  \NewDocumentCommand #1 {#3} { \egroup #4 }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \NewDocumentCommandOptionalInTabular_aux:nnnn {x}
\ExplSyntaxOff
% ======== end ========


% then you can just use \NewDocumentCommandOptionalInTabular to replace \NewDocumentCommand
\NewDocumentCommandOptionalInTabular \ingredient {O{} m m}{
    #1 #2 & #3 \\
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{r|l}        
        \ingredient[\multicolumn{2}{l}{Head} \\]{test1}{test2}
        \ingredient[test3]{test4}{test5}
        \ingredient{test6}{test7}
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Inspired by [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/549873/250119).