# How do I make all \vspace in a document visible?

Tags: overlays, vspace

I have various `\vspace` commands spread in a large document. Can I make them all visible by re-defining it somehow in the preamble?

I have positive and negative arguments to it. I imagine negative vspaces might be shown as a red vertical bar of some length (say 3cm, in the page background?) and positve ones as a green bar.

The actual space the command or the text uses should not be changed.

This could be an excerpt:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 

\vspace{-0.5pc}

Nunc in ultrices ante, sit amet aliquam enim. 
Mauris auctor ornare nulla, ac elementum nibh dapibus vitae.

\vspace{1pc}

Aliquam accumsan, metus vitae lobortis maximus, ligula 
tellus vehicula ipsum, eu posuere augue dolor nec est.
\vspace{-0.2pc}

Aenean id felis sit amet odio pulvinar suscipit quis sed nulla. 
Donec sit amet sapien iaculis purus ultricies ornare.
```

Sometimes the `\vspace` is between paragraphs, sometimes it is attached to its end or beginning.

I played around with `\rule` TikZ and overlays but could not at all get it to work.

*Update:*

I replaced all `\vspace` in the doc with `\tvspace` and defined that as:

```
\newcommand{\tvspace}[1]{%
\vbox to0pt{\rlap{%
  {\color{red}\rule{1pt}{\dimexpr#1*-1}}%
  {\color{green}\rule{1pt}{#1}}}%
}\vspace{#1}%
}
```

That seems to solve the horizontal box problem (`\rlap`), but the vertically the overlap seems not to work at all. I do not understand enough of how the boxes work.

With my color bars: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0uw4.jpg

Without my color bars: https://imgur.com/a/QrZs8

Alas, not non-intrusive at all.

The `tvspace` in question is here:

```
\tvspace{-0.5pc}In diesem Kapitel...
```

Comment: Have a look at `Lua-visual-debug` package

Comment: Thanks, I will, out of curiosity. But LuaTeX is not an option. I have to use pdftex.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83775

Comment: Normally a large document with a lot of manual `\vspace` has a 'bigger' problem.  Why do you have to use the command so often?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Quite sure the "bigger problem" is only the strict wished of the customer. I don't have "so many", like its on every page. But on some pages (say, 1/10th) I squeezed a tiny little bit, for example to get the last line of the listing onto the page. After I finished the whole document a central property changed (margin before second level heading). And I hope I don't have to start over from scratch but see where my old \vspaces are useless because the page break shifted.

Answer (score 4):

This is enough?

> [image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\vspace#1{%
{\color{red}\rule{1pt}{\dimexpr#1*-1}}%
{\color{green}\rule{1pt}{#1}}}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 

\vspace{-0.5pc}

Nunc in ultrices ante, sit amet aliquam enim. 
Mauris auctor ornare nulla, ac elementum nibh dapibus vitae.

\vspace{1pc}

Aliquam accumsan, metus vitae lobortis maximus, ligula 
tellus vehicula ipsum, eu posuere augue dolor nec est.

\vspace{-0.2pc}

Aenean id felis sit amet odio pulvinar suscipit quis sed nulla. 
Donec sit amet sapien iaculis purus ultricies ornare. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Almost, but not quite. If the `vspace` is heading or trailing the paragraph it seems to create a horizontal box. See https://imgur.com/a/XZGgP And if I am not mistaken, no `\vspace` is applied, either, in that case... I think?

Comment: (1) If it seem sometimes a horizontal box is just because the vertical space is small  and it appear just were  `\vspace` was inserted  but it is always a vertical line. (2) `\vspace` is always applied except on top of page, but within a paragraph have no effect until the line break. Try  `lorem \vspace{10em} ipsum ....` with/without the macro a you will see clearly. `