# Why does hiding a table row using xithen cause the alignment of multirow to break?

Tags: conditionals, multicolumn

**TLDR:** I try to write a class that shows/hides table rows conditionally. When a row is hidden just before `\multicolumn` is used, an error is triggered.

Let me first give you an M(N)WE for simpler dicussion:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{xifthen}
% Put some data in macros. This wil be imported later using \input{...}
\newcommand{\TaskA}{Some description comes here}
\newcommand{\TaskB}{Some other description}
\newcommand{\TaskC}{}
\newcommand{\HoursA}{1}
\newcommand{\HoursB}{3}
\newcommand{\HoursC}{0}

\newcommand{\printline}[1]{\ifthenelse{ \equal{\csname Task#1\endcsname}{} }{}{%
    #1 & \csname Task#1\endcsname & \csname Hours#1\endcsname & 42 \\%
}}

\begin{document}
\section{Correct behavior}
\begin{tabular}{|l l | c c }
A & Some description comes here & 1 & 42 \\
B & Some other description & 3 & 42 \\
\multicolumn{2}{|r|}{Sum:} & 4 & 82 \\
\end{tabular}

\section{Error is created}
\begin{tabular}{| l l | c c }
\printline{A}
\printline{B}
\printline{C}
\multicolumn{2}{|r|}{Sum:} & 4 & 82 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I wanted to write a class that outputs a table depending on the values of a set of macros. I dropped here the iteration thing and wrote it explicitly for sake of simplicity. If a condition is met (in the MWE only an empty task name is checked but the check is more complex in the final class) the complete row should be hidden.

I added one table that is rendered completely manually and that is working perfectly fine. However once I use macro to typeset a single row, that does no longer work as expected. First, I get a LaTeX error

```
Misplaced \omit.
\multispan ->\omit 
                   \@multispan 
l.28 \multicolumn{2}{|r|}{Sum:}
                                & 4 & 82 \\
```

Additionally, the output has no real cell spanning over two columns but the first column is somehow added as well.

[image: LaTeX output of test code]

Fun fact if one disables the row `B` and enables `C` (just switch the macro names), the effect seems not to happen. So I suspect that I am triggering an issue with the `\multicolumn` macro.

After reading [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69606/misplaced-omit-multispan-with-newcommand) and trying out the approach with `DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand`, I suspect the problem is the `\ifthenelse` structure. Am I required to go with basic (plain) TeX here?

---

**Edit 1:**
I got some anseers/comments (thank you!) but I have the problem that I cannot simply expand these to my needs (with my state of knowledge). So I might need to specify what tests I need more explictly:
First, you must knw that there are not one but 2 time entries (call them `HoursX` and `HoursExtX`).
The row should be dropped if any of these are true:

- The task name (`TaskX`) is empty
- The task name is undefined (optional)
- The `HoursX` **and** the `HoursExtX` are zero
- The `HoursX` **and** the `HoursExtX` are empty
- Optionally if `HoursX` and `HoursExtX` are both undefined

So I need the option to generate logical statements and check for empty string and numerical zero.

Comment: The contents in the beginning of a table cell must be expandable for `\multicolumn` to work. Try replacing the ifthenelse test with `\expandafter\ifx\csname Task#1\endcsname\@empty \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks for the hint but this seems in my understanding to only outpu the checked value. I edited my question to make this more specific.

Answer (score 2):

You need an expandable test and `\ifthenelse` isn't one of them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
% Put some data in macros. This wil be imported later using \input{...}
\newcommand{\TaskA}{Some description comes here}
\newcommand{\TaskB}{Some other description}
\newcommand{\TaskC}{}
\newcommand{\HoursA}{1}
\newcommand{\HoursB}{3}
\newcommand{\HoursC}{0}

\newcommand{\printline}[1]{%
  \ifcsempty{Task#1}{}{#1 & \csname Task#1\endcsname & \csname Hours#1\endcsname & 42 \\}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{Correct behavior}

\begin{tabular}{|l l | c c }
A & Some description comes here & 1 & 42 \\
B & Some other description & 3 & 42 \\
\multicolumn{2}{|r|}{Sum:} & 4 & 82 \\
\end{tabular}

\section{No error}

\begin{tabular}{| l l | c c }
\printline{A}
\printline{B}
\printline{C}
\multicolumn{2}{|r|}{Sum:} & 4 & 82 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A higher level implementation where we also check whether `\Task#1` is undefined, so you don't need to, say, define `\TaskC` to empty.

```
\documentclass{article}


% Put some data in macros. This wil be imported later using \input{...}
\newcommand{\TaskA}{Some description comes here}
\newcommand{\TaskB}{Some other description}
\newcommand{\HoursA}{1}
\newcommand{\HoursB}{3}
\newcommand{\HoursC}{0}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \tl_if_blank:n { v } { p,T,F,TF }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\printline}{m}
 {
  \bool_lazy_and:nnT
   { \tl_if_exist_p:c { Task#1 } } % \Task#1 exists
   { ! \tl_if_blank_p:v { Task#1 } } % \Task#1 is not empty
   { #1 & \csname Task#1\endcsname & \csname Hours#1\endcsname & 42 \\}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{Correct behavior}

\begin{tabular}{|l l | c c }
A & Some description comes here & 1 & 42 \\
B & Some other description & 3 & 42 \\
\multicolumn{2}{|r|}{Sum:} & 4 & 82 \\
\end{tabular}

\section{No error}

\begin{tabular}{| l l | c c }
\printline{A}
\printline{B}
\printline{C}
\multicolumn{2}{|r|}{Sum:} & 4 & 82 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have never heard of these macros with underscores. I will have to get a hold of them before I can see if they will work in my case. I added a few comments on my question to clarify what I need exactly.