# Error with \newcommand using \multicolumn in table

Tags: macros, multicolumn

I want to define a new command `\tableheadline` that (1) formats the headline text in some way and (2) takes an optional argument for spanning multiple columns while centering the headline.
 I tried the following implementation:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\newcommand{\tableheadline}[2][1]{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{\textit{#2}}}
% \newcommand{\tableheadline}[2][1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{#2}}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}[\textwidth]{cc} 
    \tableheadline[2]{C}
    \tableheadline{A} & \tableheadline{B} \\
    0 & 1 \\
    2 & 3 \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This, however, gives me an error:

```
! Misplaced \omit.
\multispan ->\omit
                   \@multispan
l.8 \tableheadline[2]{C}
```

I also get the error when I do not even use the optional argument (see commented line in the MWE). Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: This seems to be similar: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67947/multicolumn-within-a-newcommand-error

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out a solution based on the linked thread, yet. Is this obvious for you?

Comment: Just said that this is a similar question... Didn't manage to make it work but is still similar (source of the problem is the one mentioned by egreg in his answer: His answer works if you add a `\\\` that you missed in the end of first tabular line)

Comment: Yes, that's true. Good spot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A command with optional argument stops the scanning for `\omit` and starts a cell; when `\multicolumn` is then seen it's too late.

You can use `xparse`, though:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\tableheadline}{O{1}m}{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{\textit{#2}}}
```

This is only possible when the optional argument is not the last argument in the list, but this is your case.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\tableheadline}{O{1}m}{%
  \multicolumn{#1}{c}{\textit{#2}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
\tableheadline[2]{C} \\
\tableheadline{A} & \tableheadline{B} \\
0 & 1 \\
2 & 3 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notes.

1. `[\textwidth]` does nothing at all: the optional argument can be `t`, `b` or `c`, anything else is ignored.
2. You were missing `\\` for ending the first row.
3. Don't use `minimal` for examples.

Comment: Does this compile for you with the MWE in the original question? For me, it doesn't :/

Comment: @seyfe Yes, it does, provided you fix the missing ``\\``.

Comment: Oh yes thanks a lot! The `\textwidth` was a remainder of the tabularx environment, I was using before. The missing `\\` was key! Why shouldn't one use minimal? I thought it is used for debugging purposes.