# Logic before a table row when first cell is \multicolumn

Tags: longtable, multicolumn, nicematrix

This is related to a previous [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/662900/using-multicolumn-to-remove-vertical-lines-in-row-works-but-not-when-used-in-a) that was well answered by [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg).  I would like to typeset the following without the vlines around cells (1,0) and (3,0):

[image]

Using the code below, would, in principle, do that.  However, the `\refstepcounter` call before the `\multicolumn` gives an `\omit` related error, like in the [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/662900/using-multicolumn-to-remove-vertical-lines-in-row-works-but-not-when-used-in-a). Tried various things, but in general the question is, how to affect some logic per table row, in a single macro, when the first cell in that row is a `\multicolumn` given that, apparently, `\multicolumn` must be the first command in an expansion?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\newcounter{tablerowi}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\mc}{m}{\multicolumn{1}{l}{#1}}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\tableRow}{smm}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \mc{} & \mc{#3} & \mc{\thetablerowi} \\
  }{%
    \refstepcounter{tablerowi}
    \mc{#2} & \mc{#3} & \mc{\thetablerowi} \\
  } 
}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}[c]{|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|}    
    \hline
    month & name & month \#\\\hline
    \tableRow{November}{Election Day}
    \tableRow*{November}{Thanksgiving}
    \tableRow{December}{Advent}
    \tableRow*{December}{Christmas}\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already stated the problem in the question itself. There cannot be `\refstepcounter{tablerowi}` before `\mc`.

Workarounds: (weird but works)

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\newcounter{tablerowi}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\mc}{m}{\multicolumn{1}{l}{#1}}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\tableRow}{smm}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \mc{} & \mc{#3} & \mc{\thetablerowi} \\
  }{%
    \mc{\refstepcounter{tablerowi}#2} & \mc{#3} & \mc{\thetablerowi} \\
    %\mc{#2}\refstepcounter{tablerowi} & \mc{#3} & \mc{\thetablerowi} \\  % this works too as long as tablerowi is not used inside #2
  } 
}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}[c]{|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|}    
    \hline
    month & name & month \#\\\hline
    \tableRow{November}{Election Day}
    \tableRow*{November}{Thanksgiving}
    \tableRow{December}{Advent}
    \tableRow*{December}{Christmas}\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In the (statistically unlikely) case you want to learn the details of TeX, read the TeXbook/TeX by topic (more resources → [package writing - Where do I start LaTeX programming? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12668/where-do-i-start-latex-programming?noredirect=1&lq=1))

Comment: Thanks user202729.